# How large can the change in sound velocity in a solid be?

Tags: acoustics, elasticity

It is known that the "speed of sound" in air is not actually constant, but varies a lot with temperature and composition, with in an ideal gas tending towards zero at $0$ K.

$$v_{air} = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma R T}{M}}\propto \sqrt{T}$$

This formula works quite well for inert gases, such as Helium, which show nearly a factor of $10$ change in sound velocity from room temperature to cryogenic temperatures.

[image: DOI: 10.5541/ijot.5000155148]

On the other hand, for bulk solids in the linear elastic regime the speed of sound (for longitudinal pressure waves) is given by the equation below to a first approximation:

$$v_{solid} = \sqrt{\frac{K+\frac{4}{3}G}{\rho}}$$

Where $K$ is the bulk modulus and $G$ is the shear modulus. This expression can be simplified for a rod geometry to give:

$$v_{solid} = \sqrt{\frac{E}{\rho}}$$

Where $E$ is the Young's modulus. As noted by a commenter, the expressions are more complicated in crystals with low symmetry, but roughly follows the same general idea.

All of this has got me wondering, **what is the largest change in sound velocity in bulk solids with temperature?** Note that I am only talking about bulk solids away from their melting point or other similar phase transitions (e.g. sublimation).

At first glance I would expect there to be less than a factor of $2$ change with temperature for usual solids like stainless steel or copper, but what about more exotic materials (oxides, van-der Waals materials like MoSe$_2$, etc.?)

Comment: Those expressions are for isotropic solids, but in the case of crystals the phase speeds would be much more complicated and depend on the direction of propagation.

Comment: @nicoguaro I would argue that they are not that much more complicated (anistropic, and that's about it) but my I think my question should still be valid, right?

Comment: There are up to 21 elastic constants. I think that your question is interesting, but I don't think that it is just that. Regarding your question, you can evaluate how much $E$ and $\rho$ change with temperature. For most solids, they are somewhat correlated. So, I suspect that there isn't much change.

Comment: Just to throw a "monkey wrench" into this: consider non-newtonian fluids, wherein the soundwave itself (at sufficient intensities) will greatly alter the characteristics of the material making it act as though it was a solid, and propagate as through a fluid at lower intensities.

Comment: @R. Rankin thank you for your comment. At the moment, I only want to address the linear low-intensity regime of longitudinal sound. Otherwise to do a fair comparison I would have to think about non-linear effects of sound in gases as well (e.g. shockwaves),  but that is a different question I believe.